# node.js mongodb update /db.open() issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, native

I'm using the node.js mongodo native library.

Here's the code snippet that's not working. The db.open call fails with no error. The console.log statements inside the db.open call are not printed and the db values are also not updated. Frustrating error. No clue as to how to resolve this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
function updateFriend(friendId, loc) {
        var input = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("{FRIENDS.PHONE_NUMBER :" + friendId + "}"));
        db.open(function(error, client) {
          console.log("##########################" );
          console.log("######INPUT :::: " + JSON.stringify(input));
          if(error) throw error;
          var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'test_collection');
          collection.update(input, {"$set":{"FRIENDS.$.LOC":"12.32, 88.33"}}, {safe:true}, function(err) {
            db.close();
          });
        });
}
```

Here's the mongo collection that I'm trying to update:

```
{ "FRIENDS" : [ { "PHONE_NUMBER" : "1476516777", "LOC" : "", "NAME" : "A2" } ], "OCCASION" : "cafe", "MYLOCATION" : "13.0390433,77.554942", "MYID" : "695913809", "_id" : ObjectId("503b4e41f1d9b7913d000001") }
```

EDIT: A manual db update with this command works just fine.

```
db.test_collection.update({"FRIENDS.PHONE_NUMBER":"1599181298"},{$set:{"FRIENDS.$.LOC":"13,14"}},false,true);
```

Comment: Can you show the code that creates `db`?

Comment: var server = new mongodb.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {});
var db = new mongodb.Db('test', server, {});

Comment: That looks fine.  Calling `updateFriend` should result in the console.log output regardless on the success of opening `db`.  Does your program throw an exception, hang, close silently, or ?

Comment: Hi Johny - no exception, doesn't hang, doesn't close :). So I turned on node-inspector and put a breakpoint inside the first statement in db.open and the breakpoint is never reached. This is why am baffled. The function call just returns as if nothing has happened.

Comment: function queryJSONObjects(lOrganizerId, getData) {
        var input = {};
        input.MYID = lOrganizerId;
        sys.log("INPUT" + JSON.stringify(input));
        db.close();
        db.open(function(error, client) {
          if(error) throw error;
          var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'test_collection');
          collection.find(input).toArray(function(err, docs) {
              //console.log(docs);
              console.log("DDDD");
              db.close();
              getData(docs);
          });
        });
}
this is another function which returns fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things

1. Don't open a new db connection for each request, open it once in your app and reuse the same db instance across the application. If you need access to other db's do the following

   ```
   var db1 = db.db('someotherdb')
   ```
2. Don't create collection objects, use the db.collection method. The collection object is not mean to be created and it would be a private constructor if it was possible. Do the following.

   ```
   var collection = db.collection('mycollection')
   ```

Documentation for the driver is here

http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/

Best of luck

Comment: Overall - this is the best strategy that I could clearly understand and implement. Thanks Chris. So my code now looks like db.open(function (err, db) { //do stuff with multiple functions ; db.close() });